# JavaFX components are missing, and are required to run this application error after creating exe with Lanuch4j

Tags: java, javafx, launch4j

I made my first JavaFX application and I wanted to export it to *.exe*. I used IntelliJ to write code, used Maven Tools to create JAR and then Lanuch4J to convert it. From Launch logs I get

> Executing: C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Test.exe
> Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Launching the jar by `java -jar jarfile.jar` gives the same results.

I have added JavaFX to environment variables path as this is the only solution that I came up with. Maybe I did it wrong. I need help to resolve it. Also is there a way where *exe* won't need JavaFX to be installed on PC so I could share it with others that only have Java installed?

Comment: Maybe you want a [fat JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150811/what-is-a-fat-jar)?

Comment: You can take a look at my answer in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71989018/exe-using-launch4j-does-not-work-javafx-project-jar-files-need-to-be-ran-from/71990054#71990054

Comment: Another option (I have not tried this, but it should work) is to use `jlink` to create a JRE with JavaFX included, and then use that as the JRE embedded for Launch4J.

Comment: Similar: [How to make a Windows/MacOS/Linux installer for JavaFX & Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77792847/how-to-make-a-windows-macos-linux-installer-for-javafx-spring-boot-application/77794387#77794387) and [How to create a standalone .exe in Java (that runs without an installer and a JRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69811401/how-to-create-a-standalone-exe-in-java-that-runs-without-an-installer-and-a-jr).  Other resources are in the [packaging section of the JavaFX tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info).